# Angular2 change URL without affecting route

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to change query parameters without reloading the component.  I'd love to find something like RouteParams .get(), but a .set().

I've tried out Location:

```
this._location.go( '/equipment_room?category_id='+ this.selected_category.id);
```

This does "work", but it causes routing to run and generate a new component (not acceptable).

The goal is to change the url so the user can navigate back to that exact spot in the ng2 app at anytime by coping/pasting the URL.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `Location API` is the one you are looking for. Please show us your code with plunker.